# pass completion block from swift to back to objective

Tags: objective-c, swift, closures, objective-c-blocks

Trying to get completion block back from swift code, but looks like I'm doing something wrong.

My objC code which I want to replicate for my swift view controller `TestViewController`

I just need `Bool` and `BMError` back in completion block

Code in which I'm doing wrong:

```
TestViewController *changeVC = [[TestViewController alloc] initWithCompletionData:completion ];
```

My swift code which I tried to replicate like objc function:

```
@objc public class TestViewController {

    var completionData: ((Bool, BMErrors?) -> Void)?

    public required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("Not implemented")
    }

    @objc public init(completionData completion: ((Bool, BMErrors?) -> Void)?) {
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
        self.completionData = completion
    }

    func verifySuccess(result: QuestionResult, error: BMErrors?) {

        if (result.success) {
            // how to pass completionData
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: @Roman Podymov Did you give me answer. Could you please give me back?

Comment: What is `BMErrors`?

Comment: That is my custom class

Comment: Do you want to know how to call `completionData`? `self.completionData?(false, nil)`.

Comment: Not at all. I will repost my previous comment as an answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201217/discussion-between-roman-podymov-and-reed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `TestViewController.completionData` like this: `self.completionData?(false, error)` or `self.completionData?(false, nil)` if you don't want to pass `error`.